# Trigger Question!

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database, triggers

Greetings StackOverflow community!

For this new project I'm required to write a trigger which fires when a row is inserted into one of the tables.

I have a table called Questions which contains the following fields:

- ID - int
- Datecreated - smalldatetime
- Category_ID - int
- Value - ntext
- Timelimit - smalldatetime
- helper - ntext (nullable)

and another table User_Questions which contains the following fields:

- ID - int
- Question_ID - int
- User_ID - int
- Datecreated - smalldatetime
- helper - ntext (nullable).

Now I think i can write a trigger which extracts the Datecreated and ID fields from Questions table and adds them to a new row in the Users_Questions table. Could you please advice me on how to get the value for the User_ID field?

That would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: **1.)** Why would you want to keep the same date in two tables? That's redundant, don't do that. **2.)** how should anybody know where the `User_ID` value comes from? You're not telling that. **3.)** Is there ever a question that can belong to more than one user?

Comment: What have you tried so far please? Based on the MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: One option that I would prefer in this case would be to create a stored procedure that takes the necessary input parameters, and then does your two inputs into the two tables in a transaction. That way you control what's going on. Triggers are notoriously hard to get right, they don't scale very well - I would try to avoid triggers if ever possible (not always possible, but often, it is)

Comment: You're not telling us what **version** of SQL Server you're using - but if you're on 2005 or newer, you should **avoid** the `NTEXT` datatype - use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead!

Comment: @Tomalak yes you're right, I will remove the redundant datecreated field in the UserQuestions table. User_ID is a foreign key field which points to the ID field of the Users table. A user must be logged in before he can ask a question. 3) I don't quite understand this? WHat do you mean by that?

Comment: @Dragan If a question can only be owned by one user, then your entire `User_Questions` table is unnecessary and the `User_ID` field belongs into the `Questions` table. The two-table setup is usually reserved for 1:n relationships, not for 1:1 relationships. This would also solve your trigger question immediately and elegantly. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option that I would prefer in this case would be to create a stored procedure that takes the necessary input parameters, and then does your two inputs into the two tables in a transaction. That way you control what's going on:

(this assumes SQL Server 2005, and the ID fields are INT IDENTITY - correct??)

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertQuestion
    @Datecreated SMALLDATETIME, @Category_ID INT,
    @Question NVARCHAR(MAX), @Timelimit SMALLDATETIME,
    @helper NVARCHAR(MAX)
 AS BEGIN
    -- start transaction and a TRY..CATCH block
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY
        -- insert values into "Questions" table
        INSERT INTO 
           dbo.Questions(DateCreated, Category_ID, Question, TimeLimit, Helper)
        VALUES
            (@DateCreated, @Category_ID, @Question, @TimeLimit, @Helper)

        -- retrieve the ID of the newly inserted row
        DECLARE @QuestionID INT
        SET @QuestionID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

        -- determine the user ID from SQL Server
        DECLARE @UserID INT
        SET @UserID = SUSER_ID() 

        -- insert values into "User_Questions" table
        INSERT INTO 
           dbo.UserQuestions(QuestionID, UserID, DateCreated, Helper)
        VALUES
            (@QuestionID, @UserID, @DateCreated, @Helper)

        -- commit transaction, if everything went well
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
       -- handle your error, e.g. by logging to a table or something.....
       ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH
 END
```

Triggers are notoriously hard to get right, they don't scale very well - I would try to avoid triggers if ever possible (not always possible, but often, it is) –

Comment: Judging by your reputation I'd take your answer seriously :). From what I understand from your reply, you create a stored procedure that inserts a record in the Questions table and immediately after that inserts a new row in the User_Questions. Am I right? I think I can get the same effect by using Entity Framework. Would you recommend using LINQ for this? Up until this point my whole database logic was written using LINQ syntax with EF. I guess what I'm trying to ask is whether LINQ to Entities is a viable option to go with for this particular prob? Thank you heaps for your answer!

Comment: Oh and btw thanks for the suggestion to use NVARCHAR. When i was designing the tables i set it to NVarChar but my friend with whom i'm doing this website insisted on using ntext, dunno why. Since he has 3 years of experience i thought i'd go with whatever he suggested. Thanks for sharing the knowledge!!